# Backing up each table on MySQL in a separate dump on WIndows

Tags: batch-file, mysql

I have a MySQL database named 'abcd' and I need to run a dump for each table using a .bat file on Windows.

How can I combine the followings

```
mysql -e "show tables from abcd" -u root --password=1234
mysqldump -u root --password=1234 %%tablename > S:\Backup\MySQL\%%tablename.sql
```

into a single bat file to loop through the tables?

Thanks.

Comment: What the problem with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

> mysql -e "show tables from abcd" -u root --password=1234 > tables.txt
>
> FOR /F %%A IN (tables.txt) DO ( mysqldump -u root --password=1234 --routines --databases %%A > S:\Backup\MySQL\%%A.sql )

I don't use windows any more, this in Linux would be much easier. the /F reads the file line by line, so you would have to do some modifications and come back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to manually list the tables but to use the result of "show tables from abcd".

Comment: Have a look of that one. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  We are almost there. The tables file is correctly created but there is something wrong with the loop.

`mysqldump -u root --password=1234 users 1> users.sql`. Notice the `1` before `>`. Thanks

Comment: Is that '1' coming from the .txt file? try some ECHO %%A

Comment: Thanks. No the 1 is not in the txt. The txt looks fine and also when I echo it I get the table names without 1.

Comment: I added some parenthesis. Have a look.